# Preparation for a Linear Algebra Class

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have just entered my Junior Year as a CS student.

While I have already taken discrete math and Theory of Computation, and have not found myself needing any additional math skills thus far; I decided that I would like to take some more math courses, namely linear algebra, because I don't know what I'll end up doing down the road and it is very plausable that the knowledge will serve me well.

I took AP calc in HS. I did fairly well and I got the credit for calculus. So, I can start taking Linear Algebra whenever I want, but I don't know if this is a good idea, because it was a few years ago and I'm having a hard time recalling what I learned in that class to be honest.

For those of you who have taken it before, how dependent will my success in learning the subject be on my calculus knowledge?

Can you list some theories/ideas/formulas that I should be comfortable with before diving into this subject? ( don't be afraid to list things that you think any imbecile should know, as I may indeed be one)

Comment: PDF copies of the book Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler are pretty freely available online, if you search for just that. Reading that is probably the best thing you can do for yourself. It's a fairly short book, as textbooks go. That, plus a skimming of the Wikipedia article on Linear Algebra will be more than enough to prepare you. Do not worry about your Calculus Knowledge. Linear Algebra and Calculus are pretty different subjects.

Comment: I know some calculus courses go over vectors a little but other than that there no overlap between the two. Some people who really get calc can get linear algebra or have a hard time with it. Also just in terms of learning the material, since linear algebra has to do with vectors you the visual aspect of that to guide you through the course

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29414/755.  This violates SE rules.  In the future, please flag it for moderator attention and ask the moderators to migrate it, don't cross-post.